# Why setOnMapClickListener is not working in Kotlin?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, google-maps-android-api-2

I wanna log a message when touch on Map.But when I click nothing happen.
My kotlin code is below:

```
class MainActivity : FragmentActivity(),OnMapReadyCallback,GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener{
    lateinit var map: GoogleMap
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        map=googleMap
        map.setOnMapClickListener(this)
    }
    override fun onMapClick(p0: LatLng?) {
        Log.d("GoogleMap", "Clicked")
    }
}
```

Comment: any news on this?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the below method and please note map behavior is problematic when testing with an emulator:

```
override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap

    mMap.setOnMapClickListener(object :GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener {
        override fun onMapClick(latlng :LatLng) {
            val location = LatLng(latlng.latitude,latlng.longitude)
            mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(location))
        }
    })
}
```